# htaccess not good, some urls with and without extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What i need in my htaccess is the following:

- some urls without .php ( a few ) ( this is missing in the current htaccess)
- website always redirect to www if its without
- delete slashes if no directory ( thats working now )

I'm trying all day long, but i think its not in the right order... this is what i have:

```
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)(\.php)?(\?*)$ index.php/$1$3 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting non-www to www with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L
```

Remove .php extensions

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thx, but i need the most scripts with extension, a few without. Do you have a solution for that?